# About microsd card and upload raspbian

Tags: image-uploading, raspbian

I want to upload raspbian into the microsd card.I can format with microsd card formatter.But i can’t upload raspbian img file.Im using win32disk imager.Problem is “error21 device is not ready” So the uploading is failed.I also tried to upload with balenaetcher but it is failed too.How can i upload raspbian?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to upload raspbian into the sd card with balenaEtcher rather than win32disk.But it doesn't work